# jQuery if GET form conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$( 'body' ).replaceWith( '<iframe src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>' );
```

It replaces the whole content of the page with the iframe. However I would like that the above code to vary its iframe source if the form sent a specific value.

For example if:

```
<input name="any_other_value" value="any_value" type="radio">
```

Is selected, then the jQuery code posted above shows a different iframe.

Do you think this can be achieved with jQuery?

Comment: You should use `html` instead of `replaceWith` because it is best not to 'replace' the `<body>` tag, but to keep it in the page.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the meaning of *"previous jQuery"* or *"previous code"*.

Comment: I apologize. I've now edited the post. A form sends you to a page with a jQuery code. I'd like that depending on what option you selected on that form, jQuery can detect it and show a different output.

Comment: OK, I think the answer I've posted will solve your problem.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey — It won't. Your answer depends on the form being on the *same* page.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks to see whether the radio button is checked. If so, the `src` of the `iframe` is adjusted.

```
var desiredSrc = 'http://google.com'
if($('input[name="any_other_value"][value="any_value"]').is(':checked'))
    desiredSrc = 'http://example.com'
$( 'body' ).html( '<iframe src="' + desiredSrc + '" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>' );
```